# Firebase Database taking 10 to 12 seconds to get the data, iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase database for my chat and using a query to get the data from. Query is as follow,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {           

  self.channelRefHandle = self.channelRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userid1")
   .queryEqual(toValue: String(describing: getMyUserDefaults(key: MyUserDefaults.UserId)))
   .observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

  })
}
```

I've a database structure like below image
[image]

I'm not getting the exact issue that the above query getting too much time to load the record.
I've 9000 around record on Firebase Database.

If anyone have any idea please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: The time it takes to load the data is typically mostly a factor of the amount of data you download and the bandwidth that you're downloading it over. Without knowing those, it's hard to say anything useful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : I've posted the DB structure and all can you please guide me now? If it's possible.

Comment: 1) You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. 2) How much data are you trying to download? What bandwidth does the device have that you're downloading the data on?

Comment: First, get rid of *DispatchQueue.main.async* as it's not needed; Firebase is asynchronous. Second, that query is odd - you are querying for a child value of the key *userid2* (you are querying for a userID string), but the value is another key: value pair (which isn't a string). Lastly, 9000 nodes is really nothing. However, what's contained in those nodes is more important than the number. i.e. how much data is in those userid1 nodes?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen & Jay, I've exported the Json file, you can check the structure of Database and message, the link is https://www.dropbox.com/s/2v3vx0ckgor4rud/FirebaseJson.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Links change or go away over time so linking code and your structure in a comment is not a good idea. Please edit your question with a snippet of your Firebase structure (as TEXT please, no images) and re-read and address the above comments as the posted code won't work with the structure as is.